# Discord bot does not accept commands when other command is running

Tags: python, asynchronous, urllib, discord.py, youtube-dl

I'm developing a discord bot that can find spotify playlists and queue the tracks' youtube counterparts. I have a loop running that uses a list of tracknames to search for a video on youtube, it then grabs the top result and sends to an asynchronous function that plays it. However, whilst the bot is in this loop it does not accept other commands. Can I make this run concurrently with other commands? The following is all the code of my application

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import os
import requests
import base64
import json
import time
import discord
import shutil
from discord.utils import get
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import youtube_dl
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='s- ')

accessToken = ""

clientIDSECRET = os.getenv('SPOTIFY_ID')+':'+os.getenv('SPOTIFY_SECRET')

base64Auth = base64.b64encode(clientIDSECRET.encode("utf-8")).decode('ascii')
trackStrings = []

def pretty_print_POST(req):
    print('{}\n{}\r\n{}\r\n\r\n{}'.format(
        '-----------START-----------',
        req.method + ' ' + req.url,
        '\r\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in req.headers.items()),
        req.body,
    ))

@bot.event
async def on_ready():    
    payload={'grant_type':'client_credentials'}
    headers = {'Authorization':f'Basic {base64Auth}'}
    req = requests.Request('POST', "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", data = payload, headers = headers)
    prep = req.prepare()
    pretty_print_POST(prep)
    s = requests.Session()
    response = s.send(prep)
    global accessToken
    accessToken = json.loads(response.content)["access_token"]
    print(accessToken)

@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['sp'])
async def spotlist(ctx, userName, playlistName = "", shuffle=False, limit=100, offset=0):
    print(limit)
    if limit > 100 or limit < 0:
        await ctx.send(f'Limit out of bounds! It needs to be between 0 and 100.')
        return
    playlistId = ""
    headers = {'Authorization':f'Bearer {accessToken}'}
    if playlistName == "id":
        playlistId = userName #Username assumed to be a playlist id instead
    else:
        playlists = json.loads(requests.get(f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{userName}/playlists', headers=headers).content)
        for playlist in playlists["items"]:
            if playlist["name"] == playlistName:
                playlistId = playlist["id"]
    nextURL = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlistId}/tracks?offset={offset}&limit={limit}'
    while nextURL != None:
        trackResponse = requests.get(nextURL, headers = headers)
        tracks = json.loads(trackResponse.content)
        if(tracks["total"] <= offset):
            await ctx.send(f'Offset (third argument) is too large! Your playlist is {tracks["total"]} long.')
            return
        for track in tracks["items"]:
            trackStrings.append(track["track"]["name"] + " " + track["track"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        nextURL = tracks["next"]
        if(limit != 100):
            break

    for trackString in trackStrings:
        try:
            await play(ctx, await SearchVid(trackString))
        except:
            print("couldn't find song")

@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['j', 'joi'])
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['l', 'lea'])
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Don't think I am in a voice channel")


async def playSong(ctx):   
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))

    try:
        first_file = os.listdir(DIR)[0]
    except:
        print("No more queued song(s)\n")
        return

    song_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + "\\" + first_file)
    async def func(x):
        os.remove(song_path)
        await playSong(ctx)
    try:
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song_path), after=async_to_sync(func))
        await ctx.send(f"playing {first_file}")
        voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
        voice.source.volume = 0.07
    except:
        print("song already playing")
    still_q = len(os.listdir(DIR))
    print(f"Songs still in queue: {still_q}")


@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, url: str = ""): 

    await join(ctx) 

    Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
    if Queue_infile is True:
        DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
        try:
            _ = os.listdir(DIR)[0]
        except:
            print("No more queued song(s)\n")
            await queue(ctx, url)
            await playSong(ctx)
        else:
            await queue(ctx, url)
            await playSong(ctx)
    else:
        return

@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['s'])
async def skip(ctx):
    await stop(ctx)

@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['pa', 'pau'])
async def pause(ctx):

    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_playing():
        print("Music paused")
        voice.pause()
        await ctx.send("Music paused")
    else:
        print("Music not playing failed pause")
        await ctx.send("Music not playing failed pause")


@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['r', 'res'])
async def resume(ctx):

    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_paused():
        print("Resumed music")
        voice.resume()
        await ctx.send("Resumed music")
    else:
        print("Music is not paused")
        await ctx.send("Music is not paused")

async def stop(ctx):

    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_playing():
        voice.stop()
    else:
        print("No music playing failed to stop")


async def SearchVid(textToSearch):
    print(textToSearch)
    query = urllib.parse.quote(textToSearch)
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}):
        if not vid['href'].startswith("https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/"):
            return 'https://www.youtube.com' + vid['href']

async def queue(ctx, url: str):
    Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
    if Queue_infile is False:
        os.mkdir("Queue")
    DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
    q_num = len(os.listdir(DIR))

    queue_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + f"\\{q_num} %(title)s.%(ext)s")
    print(queue_path)
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'outtmpl': queue_path,
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        print("Downloading audio now\n")
        print(url)
        ydl.download([url])
        name = os.listdir(DIR)[-1]
        await ctx.send("Adding song " + str(name) + " to the queue")

    print("Song added to queue\n")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely suggest using the module threading. I do not currently have enough time to read your code and put it in, though I might edit this answer later.
Refer to:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Threading allows you to run multiple functions at once.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into it.

Comment: That's a bad suggestion. Why using thread when the code is asynchronous? You need make synchronous operations perform asynchronous in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using blocking libraries. Discord.py is a asynchronous library and you need to use things that don't block your code. In [Frequently Asked Questions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) you can see a example using `requests` library, that's blocking and you should use [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) to make asynchronous requests instead.